# Consistency between EM clusterings with varying starting point

Tags: clustering, expectation-maximization

I have a data set (~9 dimensions) in Weka and am running the EM clusterer with a fixed number of clusters. When changing the seed/initial point, the clusterings are very different. Is this expected?

Should there not be at least some clusters that are consistent between the clusterings?

Answer (score 0):

Only if the data is nicely Gaussian and has the right number of clusters.

If you do 9d uniform data, the resulting Gaussians will likely not be stable.

So you can use instability as a proxy to indicate if the clustering is probably not reliable.